# I am getting this error =>Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited)

Tags: html, c, arduino, esp32

I am trying to make a joystick which sends it values to an esp32 and now that I have some got the code working the ESP32 is giving me this error every time it tries to set the variable to the data it received from the webserver
ERROR:

```
20:07:31.211 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
20:07:31.211 -> 
20:07:31.211 -> Core  1 register dump:
20:07:31.211 -> PC      : 0x400db213  PS      : 0x00060c30  A0      : 0x800d26f6  A1      : 0x3ffd0670  
20:07:31.211 -> A2      : 0x00000010  A3      : 0x3ffd06ac  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000000  
20:07:31.211 -> A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x800da956  A9      : 0x3ffd0650  
20:07:31.299 -> A10     : 0x3ffd06ac  A11     : 0x3f40313e  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
20:07:31.299 -> A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000019  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
20:07:31.299 -> EXCVADDR: 0x0000001f  LBEG    : 0x400893d8  LEND    : 0x400893e3  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  
20:07:31.299 -> 
20:07:31.299 -> 
20:07:31.299 -> Backtrace: 0x400db210:0x3ffd0670 0x400d26f3:0x3ffd0690 0x400d95c5:0x3ffd06e0 0x400d7989:0x3ffd0730 0x400d79f9:0x3ffd0780 0x400d4175:0x3ffd07a0 0x400d41f1:0x3ffd07d0 0x400d47fa:0x3ffd07f0
20:07:31.312 -> 
20:07:31.312 -> 
20:07:31.312 -> 
20:07:31.312 -> 
20:07:31.312 -> ELF file SHA256: ee0eb91580876fb0
20:07:31.312 -> 
20:07:31.522 -> Rebooting...
20:07:31.522 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
20:07:31.522 -> 
20:07:31.522 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
20:07:31.522 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
20:07:31.522 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
20:07:31.568 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
20:07:31.569 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
20:07:31.569 -> load:0x40078000,len:13220
20:07:31.569 -> ho 0 tail 12 room 4
20:07:31.569 -> load:0x40080400,len:3028
20:07:31.569 -> entry 0x400805e4
20:07:31.978 -> AP IP address: 192.168.4.1
```

The data should have been printed in the serial monitor yet the esp32 is rebooting

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error is in the code that you do not show. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Check the whether memory allocated for the variable you have created, if you are using cpp it must be something like

```
int  *i; 
i =  new int;
i =  your value
delete i; // after use
```

Post your code for more details